# Best IRC server for programming channels?

Tags: irc

I've always used EFnet for IRC but discovered Freenode recently. Is this the most populated server for programmers in general?

Comment: I think this belongs to ServerFault

Comment: He's not talking about running an IRC server himself. He wants a server with a lot of existing development channels.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Freenode is one of the better general purpose OSS IRC networks. For GNOME/GTK+ technologies, most people use GIMPNet (irc.gimp.net).

Answer (score 33):

FreeNode is largely accepted as OSS support/discussion channels.

Channels such as #wikipedia, #ubuntu, #extjs, ##C, ##C++, ##OpenGL and more, are all programmer oriented.

Answer (score 9):

It's the most popular I've found.  As a lamp developer I find myself in #mysql, #jquery, and #php.